# How to remove Profiling *.gcda:Cannot open errors with python virtualenv builder?

Tags: python, jenkins

In `jenkins` output I am getting the following errors. Is this a problem or can it be silenced?

```
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Python/structmember.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Python/getcompiler.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Objects/odictobject.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Objects/enumobject.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Objects/descrobject.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Objects/cellobject.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Objects/bytes_methods.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Objects/accu.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Parser/myreadline.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Parser/parser.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/xxsubtype.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/symtablemodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/zipimport.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/stringio.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/textio.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/bufferedio.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/bytesio.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/fileio.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/iobase.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/_iomodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/opt/Python-3.6.1/Modules/_localemodule.gcda:Cannot open
```

I built python from source on the `debian 8` server.

Comment: Is `virtualenv` installed from the Debian repositories, or was it installed with the new `pip` that came along with your freshly built Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happened to me when I did `./configure --enable-optimizations`. If you remove `--enable-optimizations`, compile and install it again - these messages are not shown anymore.

To sum things up, here's an example with a fresh version of Python:

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tgz
tar xvf Python-3.6.3.tgz
cd Python-3.6.3
./configure
make
sudo make altinstall
python3.6
```

Comment: Any idea on how to solve this problem and keep optimizations enabled?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no other feedback about this matter. The solution was good enough in that particular case, so there was no incentive to keep digging. Perhaps you can use a Docker image for a specific version you need?

Comment: I will try docker, seems like the best option

Comment: Removing `--enable-optimizations` is not a great idea, see my full answer below.

Answer (score 10):

I fixed this issue by doing change owner. I was setting up homeassistant using Python 3.6.3 build using ./configure --enable-optimizations.
From my virtual env i got these errors but fixed them doing: from su / root account

```
sudo chown -R homeassistant:homeassistant /home/pi/Python-3.6.3
```

I thought maybe it could help other people ;)
Have a nice day! Ciao!

Answer (score 9):

The `gcda` files are [`gcc` profiling](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-Data-Files.html) records, which are used for seeing which functions the CPU spent most of its time in. This tells you where you can get the most bang for your buck, when optimising the code.

You can retain the Python code opinisations, but not have the profiling, by using the configuration options `--enable-optimizations --disable-profiling`. Well, worked for me.

As the `configure` script will tell you, if you do not have the `--enable-optimizations` you will lose out on the best performance.

You are *probably* getting `gcda` files because you interrupted the Python build part-way through. When you run with `--enable-optimizations` the Python build run in three phases

- Builds the code
- Runs all the `test` modules to profile the code
- Re-compiles the code to optimise it based on the profiling

It pretty common to think the `test` phase is just to check the code is working correctly, as this is what it looks like it is doing, but be patient and leave it and it will compile again, the second time omitting the profiling.

So, its better to compile with `--enable-optimizations` and without `--disable-profiling` and just wait, as you should get better code that way.

Comment: the damn thing freezes up due to known bugs in files like test_ssl (3.6) and test_faulthandler (3.7) - the recommendation should be to skip the tests as many of them are broken in various versions. Go straight to sudo make altinstall. Not a fan of python - the only reason I'm trying to install 3.7 is there's a bug in pyinstaller that breaks in in >3.8