# I am running into errors installing BioPython, modules cannot open

Tags: python, python-3.5, biopython

I followed the installation instructions as provided by the developers and installed biopython as follows: `python3.5 -m pip install biopython` 
I get the following errors (see below my message), and I think the main problem of all issues is that Python modules cannot be opened. I reinstalled Python completely, I tried to download the modules separate but nothing helped.

Does perhaps anyone has a solution?

Full output:

```
$ python3.5 -m pip install biopython
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_posixsubprocess.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_posixsubprocess.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_posixsubprocess.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_posixsubprocess.gcda:Cannot open
Collecting biopython
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/8f/454d961e821d5f600eb59885dc32aa39e3f226357f5d18a839d7ae088722/biopython-1.76-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 2.3MB 836kB/s 
Collecting numpy (from biopython)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/18/c0b937e2f84095ae230196899e56d1d7d76c8e8424fb235ed7e5bb6d68af/numpy-1.18.2-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (20.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 20.0MB 101kB/s 
Installing collected packages: numpy, biopython
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/unicodedata.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/fcntlmodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_elementtree.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_csv.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/arraymodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_multiprocessing/multiprocessing.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/termios.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/expat/xmltok.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/expat/xmlrole.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/expat/xmlparse.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/pyexpat.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_pickle.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_bisectmodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_json.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_posixsubprocess.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/grpmodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_lzmamodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_bz2module.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/zlibmodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/x86/ffi64.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/closures.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_ctypes/libffi/src/prep_cif.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_ctypes/stgdict.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_ctypes/callproc.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_randommodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_hashopenssl.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_datetimemodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/binascii.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_ssl.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/selectmodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_math.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/mathmodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/socketmodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_struct.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/media/biosys5/bigDisk/Users/Programs/Python-3.5.9/Modules/_heapqmodule.gcda:Cannot open
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Permission Denied` error has probably occurred because your user does not have write permissions in the python installation folder.

`pip install biopython --user`

OR

`sudo pip install biopython` should do the trick. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this helped also. The strange thing is that whenever I run python3.5, it prints the list of modules that cannot be opened. What does this mean, and how can I get rid of this?

Comment: This seems to be due to the use of a python version with optimisations and profiling. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47614106/13126381) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59824965/13126381). ```--disable-profiling``` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

To solve `Permission denied` problem, try to run `pip install` with `--user` flag:

```
$ python3.5 -m pip install --user biopython
```

Comment: Thanks Artem, it did solve some of the errors. But it is strange because on one hand I get the output: 'Successfully installed biopython-1.76 numpy-1.18.2'

But still the extensive lists of cannot open modules is still there. Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: It seems that you use Python version compiled with optimizations and profiling, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59824965/13134272. Try to re-install Python (maybe via `pyenv` or `conda`) or just leave these warnings as-is, unless they don't break the functionality.