# Output cluttered with profiling:skip messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, profiling, python-3.8

Every time I run any python script (.py) in my Cygwin (bash) shell, I get a huge list of `profling: ... :Skip`. I don't think it's Cygwin-related, but something with my Python setup, which is installed from the official Cygwin repos & builds.

Python itself is functioning correctly but these messages clutter my output.
How can I fix/remove them?

```
[admin@Zbook ~/Desktop]λ python3.8 --version
Python 3.8.2
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Programs/python.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/getbuildinfo.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Parser/acceler.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Parser/grammar1.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Parser/listnode.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Parser/node.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Parser/parser.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Parser/token.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Parser/myreadline.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Parser/parsetok.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Parser/tokenizer.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/abstract.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/accu.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/boolobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/bytes_methods.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/bytearrayobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/bytesobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/call.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/capsule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/cellobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/classobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/codeobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/complexobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/descrobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/enumobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/exceptions.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/genobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/fileobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/floatobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/frameobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/funcobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/interpreteridobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/iterobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/listobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/longobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/dictobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/odictobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/memoryobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/methodobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/moduleobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/namespaceobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/object.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/obmalloc.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/picklebufobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/rangeobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/setobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/sliceobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/structseq.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/tupleobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/typeobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/unicodeobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/unicodectype.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Objects/weakrefobject.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/_warnings.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/Python-ast.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/asdl.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/ast.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/ast_opt.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/ast_unparse.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/bltinmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/ceval.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/codecs.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/compile.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/context.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/errors.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/frozenmain.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/future.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/getargs.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/getcompiler.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/getcopyright.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/getplatform.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/getversion.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/hamt.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/import.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/importdl.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/initconfig.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/marshal.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/modsupport.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/mysnprintf.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/mystrtoul.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pathconfig.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/peephole.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/preconfig.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pyarena.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pyfpe.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pyhash.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pylifecycle.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pymath.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pystate.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pythonrun.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pytime.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/bootstrap_hash.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/structmember.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/symtable.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/sysmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/thread.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/traceback.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/getopt.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pystrcmp.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pystrtod.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/pystrhex.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/dtoa.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/formatter_unicode.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/fileutils.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Python/dynload_shlib.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/getpath.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/main.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/gcmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/posixmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/errnomodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/pwdmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_sre.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_codecsmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_weakref.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_functoolsmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_operator.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_collectionsmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_abc.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/itertoolsmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/atexitmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/signalmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_stat.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/timemodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_threadmodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_localemodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_iomodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/iobase.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/fileio.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/bytesio.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/bufferedio.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/textio.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/stringio.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/faulthandler.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/_tracemalloc.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/hashtable.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/symtablemodule.gcda:Skip
profiling:/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2/Modules/xxsubtype.gcda:Skip
```

Comment: This question could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47011941/how-to-remove-profiling-gcdacannot-open-errors-with-python-virtualenv-builder/47614106

Comment: `/usr/local/src/Python-3.8.2` is a local installed python. Current 3.8.x cygwin Python is 3.8.3 and it is almost all under `/usr/lib/python3.8`

Answer (score 0):

@matzeri is right! Turns out I had an old & partial Python 3.8 installation which I compiled from source long ago and totally forgot about it!

Cited messages in the output are because of the `--enable-optimizations` and maybe the `--disable-profiling` compilation flags.

I used [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454015/423548) bash script from Stack Exchange to clear this old compiled-from-source Python!